# Using sed to change string while string contains foreward slash

Tags: sed

```
sed -i  's/1006.2/Irradiance (W/m^2) 1006.2/g' file1.1
```

I want my string to read

```
Irradiance (W/m^2) 1006.2
```

However when I run it, it won't read the command because of the foreward slash (W/m^2)

How can I edit this command to make it have the output that I want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can choose most of ascii characters as delimiter like pipe :

```
sed -i 's|1006\.2|Irradiance (W/m^2) &|g' file1.1
```

Comment: DRY tip: you can use `&` in the replacement part to substitute whatever was matched: `s|1006\.2|Irradiance (W/m^2) &|g`